# WorldPay all fields in Administration Panel are disabled

Tags: umbraco, worldpay

I am a newbie using Worldpay and for this customer of mine I have to set it up for an Umbraco web application.

I was following steps mentioned in [This Article](http://www.publicvoid.dk/SetupUCommerceToIncludeRBSWorldPayAsAPaymentMethod.aspx) but stuck in 2nd step.

In Worldpay website I tried to change "Payment Response URL" but all parts were disabled and I am not able to change none of the required values.

[image: Screenshot:]

Do I have to ask my customer to change (Upgrade maybe!) their account in order to be able to change these itesm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.
The problem were with WorldPay as they did not provide required permissions!